# Cassandra Predicates on non-primary-key columns (eventtype) are not yet supported for non secondary index queries

Tags: cassandra, database-indexes, secondary-indexes

i developed a table as shown as below with primary key as id which is a uuid type

```
 id                                   | date                     | eventtype    | log      | password | priority | sessionid | sourceip     | user       | useragent
--------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------
 6b47e9b0-d11a-11e8-883c-5153f134200b |                     null | LoginSuccess |  demolog |     1234 |       10 |    Demo_1 | 123.12.11.11 |       Aqib |  demoagent
 819a58d0-cd3f-11e8-883c-5153f134200b |                     null | LoginSuccess |  demolog |     1234 |       10 |    Demo_1 | 123.12.11.11 |       Aqib |  demoagent
 f4fae220-d133-11e8-883c-5153f134200b | 2018-10-01 04:01:00+0000 | LoginSuccess |  demolog |     1234 |       10 |    Demo_1 | 123.12.11.11 |       Aqib |  demoagent
```

But when i try to query some thing like below

```
select * from loginevents where eventtype='LoginSuccess';
```

i get an error like below

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Predicates on non-primary-key columns (eventtype) are not yet supported for non secondary index queries"
```

This is my table

```
cqlsh:events> describe loginevents;

CREATE TABLE events.loginevents (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    date timestamp,
    eventtype text,
    log text,
    password text,
    priority int,
    sessionid text,
    sourceip text,
    user text,
    useragent text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

How can i solve this

Comment: How did you define your primary key? Does it simply consist of `id`? If you don't need immediate consistency, you may be able to define a materialised view of this table in which predicates on `eventtype` are possible.

Comment: Could you share your table definition as well? Regarding materialized views, please read [Materialized Views marked experimental](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201710.mbox/%3CetPan.59f24f38.438f4e99.74dc@apple.com%3E)

Comment: Added table please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An immediate answer to your question would be to create a secondary index on the column `eventtype` like this:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON events.loginevents (eventtype);
```

Then you can filter on this particular column :

```
SELECT * FROM loginevents WHERE eventtype='LoginSuccess';
```

However this solution can badly impact the performances of your cluster.

If you come from the SQL world and are new to Cassandra, go read an introduction on cassandra modeling, like [this one](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling).

The first thing is to identify the query, then create the table according to.

In Cassandra, data are distributed in the cluster according to the partition key, so reading records that belong to the same partition is very fast.

In your case, maybe a good start would be to group your records based on the `eventtype` :

```
CREATE TABLE events.loginevents (
  id uuid,
  date timestamp,
  eventtype text,
  log text,
  password text,
  priority int,
  sessionid text,
  sourceip text,
  user text,
  useragent text,
  PRIMARY KEY (eventtype, id)
```

)

Then you can do select like this :

```
SELECT * FROM loginevents WHERE eventtype='LoginSuccess';
```

or even :

```
SELECT * FROM loginevents WHERE eventtype in ('LoginSuccess', 'LoginFailure');
```

(It's not a perfect model, it definitely needs to be improved before production.)

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra, you can only query on the PRIMARY key and some of the clustering columns and it's not possible to query on all of the fields.
if you want to query on "eventtype" you should use secondary indexes in the definition of table or index table by Apache Solr and query using Solr.Some things like below:

```
CREATE INDEX loginevents_type
   ON events.loginevents (eventtype);
```