# Select all rows from cassandra having created_on in a given range

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra table which has following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE testKeySpace.table1 (
    field1 text,
    field2 text,
    field3 text,
    field4 text,
    id uuid,
    created_on timestamp,
    updated_on timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((field1, field2, item_id), field3, field4)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (field3 ASC, field4 ASC)
```

The data has been added over the time. And in recent requirements, I have to fetch data from this table based on created_on.

Fetch query is like this: Given 2 timestamps t1 and t2, I have to get all rows which were created between t1 and t2.

Now I have am using following query to get all this data:

**`select * from testKeySpace.table1  where created_on >= t1 and created_on <=t2;`**

This gives me following error:
**`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Predicates on non-primary-key columns (created_on) are not yet supported for non secondary index queries`**

What I have tried:
 [Another Question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868299/cassandra-predicates-on-non-primary-key-columns-eventtype-are-not-yet-supporte)

I added the index on created_on using query: **`CREATE INDEX indexKey ON testKeySpace.table1 (created_on);`**

Still no success. I am getting the same error.
Can anyone help me here. I come from sql domain and don't have much exposure to cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't work this way - you can perform range queries only on the clustering columns, and in limited amount of cases - usually this is done inside the single partition.  Secondary indexes provide you an ability to perform query, but only for exact value, not for the range of values.  There is very experimental support for range queries in the [SASI](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058), but it's very buggy, and not recommended for use.

If you're using DataStax Enterprise (DSE), then you can create DSE Search index on that column, and you'll get necessary functionality. If you don't have DSE, then you can do such query via Spark, but it will be very slow, as you'll need to load all data from your database to perform filtering of the data.

I recommend to do DS201 course on [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) to understand how Cassandra works, and DS220 course to learn how to model data in Cassandra (hint: data model in Cassandra starts with queries that will be executed on that data).

Comment: I am using apache Cassandra, so DSE is not an option. Secondly, as you suggested, to query using Spark, I think there will be more overhead. I can use limit offsets and process data on my own. Should I use spark over manual processing?

Comment: Effective scanning of big amounts of data isn't very easy. You can of course do it like this: https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java - it uses the same approach as Spark. But Spark will allow you easier parallelize data processing...

Comment: For now, the best solution looks is to add this column into clustering column. Forcing me to create new table, copy data and then this type of range queries can be performed. Anyway, exploring all these options was so good.

Comment: yes, if you make this column as first clustering column, then you'll able to push filtering to Cassandra side, although you will still need to do a full table scan